# How to install h264 library for pyhton3 on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, h.264

it is like:

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement OpenH264 (from versions: )
 No matching distribution found for OpenH264"
```

when ı write command on cmd.

When I write `pip3 install av`,it is

```
"Command "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-vov37kc8\\av\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-record-m6047npy\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-vov37kc8\av\".
```

I tried to install the old version pip(ı had the new pip).But anything changes.Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have an existing installation of FFmpeg/Libav as required? See the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/av/): "If you want to use your existing FFmpeg/Libav, the C-source version of PyAV is on PyPi"

Comment: yes.I try it as be explained on pypi page.But there are errors.ı download using pip install ffmpeg-python.

Comment: ffmpeg-python is not what you need. You need to download and install the liibrary. That you will have to do manually. Alternatively you can consider switching to using conda which is much better at handling the dependencies

Comment: Now,I download openh264 library from https://github.com/cisco/openh264.And then ı'll put into /site-packages.thats' enough?(Im beginner about it:))

Comment: I am sure that is not the correct library, also that is not how you install it. With the level of knowledge you have it would be easiest to Uninstaller your python and then download ana/miniconda. Then use `conda install av`

Answer (score 0):

ı tried with anaconda.But its :PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- openh264

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/pkgs/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/pkgs/noarch

  and more than that
  To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
  looking for, navigate to

  https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.